# Parallel writing to MySQL Database table - Will cause any problems?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a PHP script, which starts another php script multiple times in an foreach loop. The other php scripts writes data to the same database table.

Will this cause any problems, because there will be around 30 processes writing to the same database table...

Or is this automatically handeled by MySQL ?

Thanks you!

Bye,
WorldSignia

Comment: currently i have a script whish does nearly the same - mass update db table unsing multiple php processes. works fine.

Comment: Thats exactly one of the reasons you use databases and not flat files. It will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you are writing. `INSERT` can be used simultaneously. `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` might lead to conflicts.

Imagine you are executing `UPDATE ... WHERE id=2` from two scripts at once. One might overwrite the other. You need to implement some locking facility.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine until two processes attempt to modify/retreive the same row(s). If you suspect you might run into such problems, you may take a look at mysql transactions(You need mysql server 5 or later for it) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html